# Selecionar input com uma determinada classe dentro de um form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um form e dentro deste form estou adicionando um determinado  `input` dinamicamente via `jquery` utilizando um botão, esses inputs vão para um `array` em uma controller C#.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente eu estou fazendo assim:

```
  for (var j = 0; j < numeroDePiscinas; j++) {
            formdata.append("Piscinas", $("#piscina"+j).val());
        }
```

O problema e que essa lógica não vai funcionar mais porque  o usuario ira poder
pode remover esses inputs, eu usava o `Id` do input de acorodo que era adicionado , ex `posição 1`, `id=piscina1`

O que eu quero fazer é pegar todos os inputs com a classe `inputPiscina` e enviar o seu valor para a controller, eu tentei algo assim :

```
 $("#form:formPiscina").each(".inputPiscina",
            function() {
                formdata.append("Piscinas", $(this).val());
            });
```

mas não funcionou, tse alguém puder me ajudar, se alguém souber alguma forma melhor de fazer isso, eu ficaria agradecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se já tens um objeto `formdata` podes enviar um array para essa chave. Algo assim:

```
var piscinas = $("#form:formPiscina .inputPiscina").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get(); // o ".get()" é para gerar uma array nativa e não uma coleção jQuery
formdata.append("Piscinas", piscinas);
```

Comment: Legal, vou tentar essa forma também, uma pergunta rapida  o que o `.map` faz, sou bem leigo nessa parte.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o .serialize() do jQuery com essa função você pegar todos os dados do seu form de forma correta para envio. ficaria dessa forma:

```
jQuery('form').serialize();
```

Aqui um exemplo do código :

[JSFIDDLE EXEMPLO](https://jsfiddle.net/f64gbq7s/)

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma lida sobre **delegação de eventos**, mais espeficamente sobre **propagação de eventos**, na [documentação oficial](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation) da biblioteca jQuery.

Resumidamente:

> A delegação de eventos refere-se ao processo de utilização da
>   propagação de eventos (*bubbling*) para lidar com eventos em um nível
>   superior no DOM do que o elemento no qual o evento se originou. Isso
>   nos permite anexar um único *event listener* para elementos que
>   existem agora ou no futuro.

Um exemplo mínimo seria assim:

```js
// "click": evento
// ".inputPiscina": elemento filho que esse evento deve ser aplicado
$( "#meuform" ).on( "click", ".inputPiscina", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).attr("id") );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <form id="meuform">
        <input id="piscina1" type="text" class="inputPiscina">
        <input id="piscina2" type="text" class="inputPiscina">
        <input id="piscina3" type="text" class="inputPiscina">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Você pode adaptar o exemplo para o seu caso, selecionando o `form` e delegando o evento `change` para os `input`s filhos que possuam a classe `.inputPiscina`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acabei resolvendo logo após postar a pergunta

Usei o seguinte código:

```
   $("input:text.inputPiscina").each(
            function() {
                formdata.append("Piscinas", $(this).val());
            });
```

Assim eu fui em todos os inputs do tipo text que tinham a classe `inputPiscina` e enviei os dados para minha controller.